# Как заменить фрагмент в ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Есть `ViewPager, ViewPagerAdapter,TabLayout` и три фрагмента `Fagment1, Fragment2, Fragment3`. ViewPager отображает 2 фрагмента.

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewPagerAdapter mVPAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment_1(), "");
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment_2(), "");
viewPager.setAdapter(mVPAdapter); 
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Как заменить Fragment 1 на 3 динамически?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Создайте метод замены фрагмента в адаптере.
2. Сделайте адаптер расширяющим `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
3. Сразу после замены фрагмента вызовите `mVPAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`
4. Добавьте в адаптер вот этот метод:

   ```
   @Override
   public int getItemPosition(Object object)
   {
       return POSITION_NONE;
   }
   ```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что мне нужно будет использовать FragmentStatePagerAdapter вместо ViewPagerAdapter?

Comment: @Igor, да, всё верно

Comment: @Igor, там много нюансов. Я использую предложенный и у меня он работает. До этого использовал другие и они работали только с подпорками из множества костылей.

Comment: 1. Когда Вы пишете -  "метод замены фрагмента", что Вы имеете в виду? У меня фрагменты хранятся:  
 List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
 
Я написал метод замены фрагмента в этом ArrayList:
 public void replaceFrag(int position,Fragment fragment) {
         mFragmentList.set(position, fragment);
 }

По нажатию кнопки я его вызываю.
 mVPAdapter.replaceFrag(0, new Fragment_03());
        mVPAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   
Но первый фрагмент не меняется.

Comment: 1. да, вы всё верно поняли. 2. См. обновлённый ответ (п.4) - должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо! Все Ок.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36388/discussion-between-igor-and-).